Finding the torque required to turn a cart resting on 4 wheels
I am building a cart that has two handles on the bottom face. The cart is basically a table resting on castor wheels, one on each leg. If I apply a couple on the handles, the cart will turn. I am trying to figure out the torque required to turn the cart by 90 degrees.
Any ideas on how to approach this problem?
